# Docker `file does not exist` Error on multi stage build COPY command

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

While build the following Dockerfile, I get the error "COPY failed: stat dispatcher: file does not exist" but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
FROM golang
COPY ["dispatcher.go", "dispatcher.go"]
RUN go build dispatcher.go

FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 dispatcher .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an explicit path when COPYing the `dispatcher` file.
Note that the image `golang` has `/go` as working directory.

```
FROM golang
COPY ["dispatcher.go", "dispatcher.go"]
RUN go build dispatcher.go

FROM scratch
COPY --from=0 /go/dispatcher /usr/local/bin/dispatcher
```

Output (with `podman` but `docker` should work the same way):

```sh
$ docker build .
Emulate Docker CLI using podman. Create /etc/containers/nodocker to quiet msg.
[1/2] STEP 1/3: FROM golang
[1/2] STEP 2/3: COPY ["dispatcher.go", "dispatcher.go"]
--> Using cache 0ea9f7534e15e49bf768e986c69bcde27001d26d674d6681ceed3096438b2d35
--> 0ea9f7534e1
[1/2] STEP 3/3: RUN go build dispatcher.go
--> Using cache 357be3e894ec59a274ef5dc7dda237743e4ab1d389ff4d247288b31987be0ae6
--> 357be3e894e
[2/2] STEP 1/2: FROM scratch
[2/2] STEP 2/2: COPY --from=0 /go/dispatcher /usr/local/bin/dispatcher
[2/2] COMMIT
--> 942793c6573
942793c6573dbe63136d329f60ccecd1eea45b40ab61703ec363e6291cc2e9f4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while compiling Golang executable from Alpine base image and I was trying to copy and execute it on python based image.

It was happening because program was compiled for one environment and was used in another env.

Following solution worked for me.

I required to build my executable for linux by setting the GOOS environment variable.

For example, instead of building my binary like:

```
RUN go install github.com/google/osv-scanner/cmd/osv-scanner@v1
```

It should be built like this:

```
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on \
    go install github.com/google/osv-scanner/cmd/osv-scanner@v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is my template for golang and docker, it might help you:

Before i have use this command

```
go mod init
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

```
#### BUILD STAGE
FROM golang:1.18-alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base
WORKDIR $GOPATH/src/project/

# Copy project files into the builder
COPY . .

RUN go build -a -mod=vendor -ldflags '-linkmode external -w -s -extldflags "-static"' -o ./myapp

#### IMAGE DEFINITION
FROM alpine:3
# Upgrade system dependencies for security patches or bug fixing
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the programm with for uid 1000 and gid 1000
COPY --chown=1000:1000 --from=builder /go/src/project/myapp myapp

CMD ["./myapp"]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).